# Ldap for PHP is not working in ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, ldap

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in /home/runcloud/webapps/ldap/api.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/runcloud/webapps/ldap/api.php on line 13

I have installed ldap using below cmd

```
sudo apt-get install php-ldap
```

I have also tryied Enable the LDAP module in  php.ini file

```
extension=ldap.so
```

I am using Ubuntu server from aws and nginx for my php application

Comment: Hi, which php version are you using ? are you able to see it in ```phpinfo()``` or ```php -m``` in php-cli and after ```sudo apt-get install php-ldap``` did you restarted the php-fpm service..

Comment: Php 7.4 version I am using. I have also performed above steps but still the same

Comment: make ```sudo apt install php7.4-ldap``` if not available use ondrej repo